# Removing repeating data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a join query that produces the results I want but it also inculded repeating data that I don't want.

Here is the commands

```
SELECT cust_id, cust_fname, cust_lname, street_address, apt, city, state, zip,  h_phone, m_phone, o_phone, cu_o.order_id, order_date, s_notes, donut_id, donut_name, donut_des, donut_cost, li.donut_qty
FROM customer cu
RIGHT JOIN cust_order cu_o
ON cu.cust_id = cu_o.co_cust_id
JOIN line_item li
ON li.li_order_id = cu_o.order_id
JOIN donut 
ON li.li_donut_id = donut.donut_id
;
```

And this is the output

[image: SQL Output]

Comment: So I don't want the customer info repeating.

Comment: Why are you using `RIGHT JOIN`? Can you have an order without a matching customer?

Comment: If you don't repeat the customer, how will you show all the orders for the same customer?

Comment: When you render the data, that's when you do a break-sort and display the repeating data once, then just the details. You don't do that in the SQL that is used to generate the output.

Comment: Maybe you should include the expected output in your question.  Because with all the different doughnuts, a distinct or group by won't help much.

Comment: I want the everything from cust_id to s_notes to show once and everything else to look the way it looks in the picture.

Comment: Understood; try to understand my answer and with a little creativity you will be able to do this in your bigger example. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Although I believe that this is not SQL's job to do this, I learned in another thread (sadly I cannot remember which one) that it can indeed be done with use of parameters. Here is a minimal and verifiable example ([with a demo here](http://rextester.com/WOMXQD54861)):

**EDIT**

I realised that the original answer was missing the proper ordering of the result, so the statement is a bit more involved (you must have ordered your result set first before applying the parameter trick).

```
drop table if exists t;
drop table if exists u;

create table t (id int, name varchar(10));
create table u (id int, tid int, val varchar(10));

insert t values (1, 'A'), (2, 'B'), (3, 'C');
insert u values (1, 1, 'x'), (2, 1, 'y'), (3, 2, 'z'), (4,2,'w'),(5,3,'q');

select x.name, x.val from (
select o.id, case when o.name <> @test then o.name else '' end as name, 
       @test:=o.name, o.val 
from (select t.id, t.name, u.val from u join t on u.tid = t.id order by t.name) o
join (select @test:='') test
) x
order by x.id
```

This is the output for this example:

```
+-----+----+
|name | val|
+-----+----+
|A    | x  |
|     | y  |
|B    | z  |
|     | w  |
|C    | q  |
+-----+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

Then don't show it to the customer.

It is totally up to you what's gonna get out, isn't it?
I don't really see what's the problem there.

And that's the way relational databases work, if you don't like it THAT much - then you may opt out for other DB types/paradigms.

PS And, well, basically there are ways to have it the way you like it.

Say, do two queries instead of one.
Or use `GPOUP_CONCAT` as an aggregator function (means, along with `GROUP BY`) to stick that donuts together for each customer.

But these are ugly & unproductive ways.